SwiftUI: declare @Environment var in view of array instead of single value
I can do this:
@Environment(Car.self) var car

But, I want to pass in an array of Cars in the environment and use that in the child view instead of just one car. I tried this:
@Environment([Car].self) var cars

Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Car].Type' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Value>'
How do I properly declare the environment variable on the view to use the array of cars instead of just the one car?

Why not make a container? struct Cars { var cars: [Car] }?

In order to be used in @Environment, your Car had to be an @Observable. But an array of Cars (aka Array where Element == Car) is entirely different type and it's not Observable. Hence cannot be used in environment. As jnddx said, create a wrapper

The @Environment initialiser that you use as @Environment(Car.self) var car takes an Observable conformant type and Array<Car> does not conform to Observable.
You can either create a wrapper type which conforms to Observable and holds an array of cars or use the other @Environment initialiser, which takes a KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Value>.
Here's a solution creating a wrapper:
@Observable
final class Cars {
  var cars: [Car] = []
}

struct CarView: View {
  @Environment(Cars.self) var cars

  var body: some View {
    Text("Cars: \(cars.cars.count)")
  }
}

And here's a solution using the KeyPath approach:
struct Car {
...
}

struct CarEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
  static var defaultValue: [Car] = []
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
  var cars: [Car] {
    get { self[CarEnvironmentKey.self] }
    set { self[CarEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}

struct CarView: View {
  @Environment(\.cars) var cars

  var body: some View {
    Text("Cars: \(cars.count)")
  }
}

